# Is it correct to use "congratulate" for someone's birthday?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, vocabulary

"I'm not going to congratulate her birthday because we're not on speaking terms"? And if not, what do we say? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you were not on "speaking terms" - would you "say" anything?

Answer (score 4):

As a native speaker, I can tell you that "congratulations" is more often used on occasions such as weddings, engagements, graduations, job promotions, and births (or expectant); but not so much for birthdays and other holidays, though it is not so much a matter of correctness here as it is custom. If you wanted to, though, you could correctly say:

"I'm not going to congratulate her *on* her birthday." or

"I'm not going to wish her a happy birthday."

For occasions such as holidays, it is most natural to say, for example:

"Happy Mother's/Veteran's/Teacher's/Star Wars Day" rather than using "Congratulations" for such occasions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems most natural to use "celebrate." "I'm not going to celebrate her birthday." Saying "Congraulate her birthday" would not make as much sense because you would usually use "congratulate" to give someone, a living thing, good wishes.

Comment: ...but you can say "congratulate someone _on_ their birthday", which is what I think the OP was trying to express.

Comment: thank you. so it would be natural sounding to say "he congratulated me on my birthday/teacher's day/mother's day/etc" Ratter?

Comment: maybe the word i'm looking for is "wish". you know like "i wont wish her a happy birthday because she didn't wish me one"

Comment: [Birthday Congratulations](https://congratulationsto.com/various/birthday_congratulations.php) @Levi I would say that we can congratulate Sb. on their birthday, but we don't actually say "congratulations".

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rattler. It's a bit contradictory though. I just read in Cambridge dictionary that: We don’t say congratulations to wish someone a happy birthday:
Happy birthday, Nora.
Not: Congratulations, Nora.

I can see the exact opposite on this website

Comment: Oh I think I got it. Thanks @Rattler

Comment: @Levi Yes, you could also say "I'm not going to _wish_ her happy birthday because we're not on speaking terms"

Comment: With no articles? "I'm not going to wish her a happy birthday" or "I'm not going to wish her  happy birthday"? @Rattler

Comment: @Levi It seems like either one can be said, but maybe the slightly better option would be with the article rather than without it.